# Problems with creating a tree in C

Tags: c, tree

I am trying to create a tree in C (I know how to make one in java, but since I am learning C I thought this would be a great way to really learn pointers), but I am not getting an output when I printf the root's data.

This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef struct Node
{
    struct Node *right;
    struct Node *left;
    int data;
} Node;

Node* create_node(int data);



Node* create_root(int nodedata)
{
    Node* root;
    root->data = nodedata;


    return root;
}

int main()
{
    Node* root = create_root(5);
    printf("%d", root->data);

    return 0;
}
```

Is the problem how I am linking the nodes with left and right pointers, or how I am returning the function to a Node pointer?

Comment: In `create_root()`, you are not allocating space for `root` to point at, so everything goes wrong from there onwards.

Comment: Why do you explicitly need to allocate space for root?

Comment: `->` is the pointer dereference operator. It essentially results in an access to some memory location whose starting address is stored in the pointer. Which means that the pointer needs to have a valid memory address. Which means you need to allocate some memory and store that address in `root`. As it is, `root` is never set and this it has a junk value and dereferencing it results in incorrect/undefined behaviour.

Comment: After you’ve allocated space, you need to set both the pointers to null as well as storing the data value.

Answer (score 0):

You should allocate memory before use.

```
Node* create_root(int nodedata)
{
    Node* root = calloc(1, sizeof(Node));
    root->data = nodedata;


    return root;
}
```